# ASP.NET Core using Azure KeyVault - Error on delegating the KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

I want to integrate my project on ASP.NET Core 1.0 with Microsoft Azure KeyVault. But it seems like Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault package is not compatible yet with "netcoreapp1.0" framework (I try to download the package using NuGet package manager and the "incompatible package" error message is shown). Therefore I import "net451" framework in the project.json shown in this block:

```
"frameworks": {
"netcoreapp1.0": {
  "imports": [
    "net451",
    "dotnet5.6",
    "portable-net45+win8"
    ]
  }  
},
```

After importing "net451" framework, the error is now gone. Now I want to initiate a new KeyVaultClient class shown in this block:

```
public void GetKeyVaultSecret()
{
    var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(this.GetTokenAsync);
    // ....
}

private async Task<string> GetTokenAsync(string authority, string resource, string scope)
{
    var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
    var authenticationResult =
        await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, this.clientAssertionCertificate);
    return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
}
```

The problem is I got this error message on `this.GetTokenAsync` which I have search the solution for hours without any luck: `Argument 1:cannot convert from 'method group' to 'KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback'`

If I change

```
var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(this.GetTokenAsync);
```

to:

```
var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient((authority, resource, scope) => this.GetTokenAsync(authority, resource, string.Empty));
```

I still got error message: `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback' because it is not a delegate type`

Anybody knows how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Regards,
Alvin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a long time abandoning this question, I've decided to look into it once more thanks to @fernacolo's answer. Turns out that at that time I used version 1.0.0 of the Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault package (which was the latest version back then, shown in Figure 1). Now version 2.0.0 of the package is available and when I find the changelog, I saw this post https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-dotnet2api-release-notes which stated that ".NET Core is supported by the 2.0 version of the Azure Key Vault .NET/C# library".

[image]
**Figure 1. Version history of Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault package**

The error is now gone without the need of importing "net451" framework in the project.json.

Answer (score 1):

The error `cannot convert from 'method group'` is because you have overloads or extensions (ie more than one method) with the name `GetTokenAsync`. Try to rename one of them, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've just tried to reproduce this problem after abandoning it for months. But it looks like the culprit was "the package had not yet supported core framework at that time"? Because at that time the latest package version was 1.0.0, and now it is 2.0.0. So I tried looking for the changelog, and I saw this post https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-dotnet2api-release-notes . The post stated that ".NET Core is supported by the 2.0 version of the Azure Key Vault .NET/C# library". It works like charm now without the need of importing "net451" framework.